# Entity setting default ACL perrmissions for CustomerUserRole

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I've created a new entity with the next configuration settings:

```
"ownership"={
    "owner_type"="USER",
    "owner_field_name"="owner",
    "owner_column_name"="user_owner_id",
    "frontend_owner_type"="FRONTEND_USER",
    "frontend_owner_field_name"="customerUser",
    "frontend_owner_column_name"="customer_user_id",
    "organization_field_name"="organization",
    "organization_column_name"="organization_id"
},
"security"={
    "type"="ACL",
    "group_name"="commerce",
    "category"="shopping"
}
```

As a result, for all customer user roles, the entity has a "Corporate" permission level for all actions. Is it possible to set default permission parameters for all roles besides migration fixtures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, the only way to set default values for the permissions configuration is by the data migration. There is a default migration that loads all the customer user roles configuration from the `Migrations/Data/ORM/data/frontend_roles.yml` file in any bundle.

Here is the example of such a YAML configuration file:
https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/RFPBundle/Migrations/Data/ORM/data/frontend_roles.yml